# How to show [Remote] Error in alertbox ()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I make sure that my Email field ValidationMessageFor only show the "Remote" error and not Required- Error.

AND Remote Error to appear in a alertbox ()

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Skriv venligst din e-mailadresse")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Ugyldig e-mailadresse")]
[Remote("DoUserExist","Home",ErrorMessage = "E-mail already in use")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string Emailaddress{ get; set; }



 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Emailaddress, new { @placeholder = "E-mailadresse" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Emailaddress)
```

Comment: Don't use `[Remote]` - write your own javascript method to call the server and display the alert in the ajax callback (but why would you want to do this?)

Comment: I show all my fields Errors in ValidationSummary.

Remote: This validates the entered email addressand show the message  immediately .

I will ONLY show Remote message IN @ Html.ValidationMessageFor (model => model.Emailaddress)

If this is not possible, is it POSSIBLE that Remote can send error message to ValidationSummary. (It should appear immediately before you click on the submit button)